# Starting from the assumption that $e^x$ is the solution to the equations $f(x)=f'(x)$ and $f(0)=1$, how may one derive the direct expansions of $e$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, exponential-function

If it is assumed that $e^x$ is the unique solution to the differential equation $f(x)=f'(x)$, how may we derive from the initial assumption the **infinite sum expansion** and the **infinite product expansion** of $e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=f'(x)\Rightarrow f'(x)=f''(x)\Rightarrow f''(x)=f'''(x)$$ It follows easily that for all $n$ $$f(x)=f^{(n)}(x)$$ Apply now Taylor expansion.

Can you finish, analogue way, with the product? Do you know the corresponding formula?

Comment: Thanks for that! It seems so obvious now that I can't believe I didn't see it right then.